# What does `kill(0,SIGINT)` do?

Tags: linux

Help I'd like to know the answer to this problem.

Will it send all the signal to all the process groups including the current process the SIGINT? Or will it block all process group with current process?

Comment: `man 2 kill`. It's there for you.

Comment: means? can u explain?

Comment: Please execute that command in your terminal. `man` is a command that gives you access to the _manual_ for many topics. `2` is the chapter (2=system calls), `kill` is the name of the system call in question.

Answer (score 5):

From [`kill(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/kill):

> ```
> int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
> ```
>
> If `pid` equals `0`, then `sig` is sent to every process in the process group
>   of the calling process.

So, your command sends `SIGINT` to every member of the current process group (which includes the current process, any process that forked from/to the current process, and any process that the shell created in a pipeline to/from the current process). See [`setpgrp(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setpgrp) , [`setsid(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid), and [`sched(7)`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/sched) for general info.

From [`signal(7)`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/signal), the default action of `SIGINT` is to terminate the process. However, since `SIGINT` is usually generated when you press ctrl-C (see [`termios(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/termios)), many processes install a handler (see [`sigaction(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction)) if they need to do some cleanup before exiting ... or even don't exit, but rather just return to their *own* main loop (for example, [`python(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/python) does this).